# Ubuntu 16.04 No Internet Access in Eduroam

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I want to connect to the eduroam network from my university. I am able to connect to the network, but I have no internet access. The connection seems to be configured correctly.
I asked our tech support what I have done wrong and all they could find is that my username does not reach the server correctly. 
In order to access the internet via eduroam you have to send your e-mail address as username. I set the connection up like that but whenever I try to access the internet it only sends the part before the '@' as the username. In my case I have:

```
username@university.de
```

but all that reaches the server is

```
username
```

Why does the NetworkManager truncate my username and how can I tell it not to?

Comment: See the solution added by a user for the University of Bath: "[Connecting to Eduroam 16.04 LTS wicd - University of Bath](http://askubuntu.com/q/829810/38585)" - might help you?