# Connecting to Eduroam 16.04 LTS wicd - University of Bath

Tags: networking, wicd

I was having trouble connecting to eduroam using wicd. Solution is posted below. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I suggest adding a line to protect your password, right after the require line: protect password *Password

Answer (score 4):

This will hopefully work for other universities too

Create the following template file for eduroam:
(/etc/wicd/encryption/templates/eduroam)

```
name = Eduroam
author = hautod
version = 1
require identity *Username password *Password
----
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
  ssid="eduroam"
  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
  pairwise=CCMP
  group=CCMP TKIP
  eap=PEAP
  ca_cert="/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt"
  identity="$_IDENTITY"
  domain_suffix_match="radius.bath.ac.uk"
  phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
  password="$_PASSWORD"
}
```

Append "eduroam" to '/etc/wcid/templates/active' so it looks similar to this:

```
wpa
wpa-peap
wpa-psk
wpa-psk-hex
wpa2-leap
wpa2-peap
wep-hex
wep-passphrase
wep-shared
leap
ttls
eap
peap
peap-tkip
eap-tls
psu
eduroam
```

You should now be able to connect using your full university email as the username and your university password.

Comment: Is there a reason for using WICD?

Comment: @CelticWarrior I'm using i3 so I wanted to use wicd-curses for management. Is there a better option?

Comment: I'm on i3 too. Consider connman.